# Does Gazebo 11 go with both ROS2 Foxy and Dashing?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If Gazebo 11 runs on both [Ubuntu Bionic and Focal](http://gazebosim.org/#accordion) and the [ROS2 Dashing also runs on Ubuntu Bionic](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Dashing-Diademata/#supported-platforms) does it follow that Gazebo 11 can be used together with ROS2 Dashing? Is that supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24802/does-gazebo-11-go-with-both-ros2-foxy-and-dashing?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The official Gazebo version for Dashing (and Eloquent) is the LTS at the time they were released, i.e. Gazebo 9, as documented on [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#dashing-diademata-may-2019-may-2021). That's what you'll get if you install `ros-dashing-gazebo-ros-pkgs`.

But there's no reason not to compile `gazebo_ros_pkgs`'s `dashing` branch from source against Gazebo 11. If it doesn't work out of the box, it shouldn't be too much work to open a PR adding support. We could also consider shipping `ros-dashing-gazebo11-ros-pkgs` from https://packages.osrfoundation.org if there's enough interest.

As for Foxy, Gazebo 11 and Ignition Citadel will be the [official versions](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/217/files).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [caiks](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25475/caiks/) on 2020-04-11**:
I have the same problem with Gazebo11 and Eloquent. I tried building `gazebo_ros_pkgs` with branch ros2 and then with branch eloquent (in `ros2.yaml`) but both builds fail in `gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_ray_sensor.cpp`.

Edit: I found a workaround by reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 and then explicitly installing gazebo9, `sudo apt-get install gazebo9` and `sudo apt-get install libgazebo9-dev`.

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-05-05**:
@chapulina Where can I express the interest for `ros-dashing-gazebo11-ros-pkgs`?